# Event handlers being duplicated when changing routes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, events, socket.io, zeromq

I have this data coming at a rate of around 30 times per second and it's being fed to my app via these event handlers. I'm using the btford.socket-io for that and the 0MQ is the responsible for getting the data to my node.js server.

I've tracked down the data coming from the node server and realized that it's coming correctly, so the duplication is actually happening on the Angular side.

What basically happens is that every time when I leave a view and come back to it, all the events are fired twice as much as before.

In the btford API Reference, he gives a suggestion of using

```
socket.forward('dataUpdate', $scope);
$scope.$on('socket:dataUpdate', function(ev, data) {
   $scope.someVar1 = data;
   $scope.someVar2 = data;
   $scope.someVar3 = data;
   $scope.someVar4 = data;
});
```

which helped for another situation. But, as I said, in this case, this event is being called 30 times a second and handled 4 times for there are 4 variables. So each time I change back to the route showing these variables, instead of doing the work 4 times, it does 8 times and then 12, 16 and goes on. With that, I'm getting a memory leak and eventually the browser crashes.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I could make it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event listener will never get removed directly, you need to remove them forcefully. You need to deregistered the listener while $destroying controller

**Code**

```
socket.forward('dataUpdate', $scope);
var socketEvent = $scope.$on('socket:dataUpdate', function(ev, data) {
   $scope.someVar1 = data;
   $scope.someVar2 = data;
   $scope.someVar3 = data;
   $scope.someVar4 = data;
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
   socketEvent(); //deregistering event while destroying controller scope.
})
```